# Python if True *unless*

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to figure out a way to return true if input is divisible by 4, but not 100 unless also by 400. I've unsuccessfully tried:

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if [year % 100 == 0 if not year % 400]:
        leap = False
    else:
        if leap % 4 == 0:
            leap = True
    return leap
```

input of 2100 is divisible by 4 and 100 but not 400, so I want it to return False.

I've come to a simple conclusion of

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
        leap = True
    elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
        leap = True
    return leap
```

But is there an easier or different way to do an unless?  Thank you.

Also, while I am primarily leaning towards python3.5 for what everyone's doing, I enjoy the simplicity of 2.7.  Any help in either would be appreciated.

Comment: I take it this is a learning exercise and that you can't just use [calendar.isleap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap)?

Comment: What about: `if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)`?

Comment: `[...]` is not a valid grouping syntax in Python; you'd be creating a list object.  In expressions, `if` would require an `else`, always, but you shouldn't be using an `if .. else ..` expression here anyway, you are not trying to produce alternative values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just point out how [`calendar.isleap`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/calendar.py#l97) does it:

```
return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

Comment: I prefer this to my answer :)

Comment: Thank you.  It took me a minute to get my mind around why this worked, but it makes sense now.

Answer (score -2):

Personally I would write it like:

```
def is_leap(year):
    if   year % 4 == 0 and year % 400 == 0: return True
    elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0: return True
    else:                                   return False
```

And I don't think it gets much simpler :)

Comment: it does, actually :)

Comment: You also don't have to repeat the condition `year % 4 == 0` twice.

Comment: Less lines isn't simpler, and I think using the fact that 400 is also divisible by 4 as cheating :P

Answer (score -2):

```
if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
        # True
# False
```

The gist of it is to handle your base condition which is that it must be divisible by 4, then handle the other ones with some conditionals.
The second if statement ensures that it is divisible by both 100 and 400

Comment: Triggered downvoters mind explaining their reasons for downvoting?